# How to find locations of an element in a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix A, that some elements of this matrix is repeated. I need to find locations of an

element in this matrix. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have to find this element without a loop ?  Do you not know how to program loops in Matlab ?  If not, we'll help.  But do show us your best code.

Comment: I know how to programloops in MATLAB and I could do this with a loop.  But it is not whole of my program. I need to it just for searching something in a matrix, my progaram has lots of for and if, so I prefer search about function in MATLAB, because of it's speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `find` can give you the row-column indices of elements.
For example

```
>> [r c] = find( A == 3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help. Syntax

```
ind = find(X)
ind = find(X, k)
ind = find(X, k, 'first')
ind = find(X, k, 'last')
[row,col] = find(X, ...)
[row,col,v] = find(X, ...)
```

Link:

http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Answer (score 1):

I see you have already got some answers on how to find elements.
Here is how to deal with duplicate elements.

First of all you can find the unique elements:

```
v = [1:4 2:5] % Suppose this is your vector
[v_unique, idx] = unique(v,'first')
```

`v_unique` is now your vector with duplicates removed. However, if you are interested in the locations of the duplicates, this will give you a list:

```
setxor(idx,1:numel(v))
```